# Variance of sample variance in terms of kurtosis

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, variance

I want to prove the formula of the variance of sample variance in terms of kurtosis for general distribution (I think it is?), which can be found here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance).
Suppose $X_1, \dotsc, X_N$ IID, with variance $\sigma^2$,
$$
\bar{X} = \frac{1}{N} (X_1 + \dotsb + X_N) \\
S = \sqrt {\frac {1} {N-1} \sum _{n=1} ^N (X_n -\bar{X})^2}
$$
Then we claim that
$$
\mathrm{Var} \left( S^2 \right)
=\frac {\sigma^4} {n} \left( \kappa - \frac{n-3} {n-1} \right)
$$
where
$$
\mu_n = \mathbb{E} (X_1^n) \\
\kappa = \sigma^{-4} \mathbb{E} \left[ (X_1 - \mu_1)^4 \right] \\
$$
Observe
$$
\sigma^4 \kappa = \mu_4 - 4 \mu_3 \mu_1 + 6 \mu_2 \mu_1^2 - 3 \mu_1^4
$$
Now, introduce a shorthand
$$
\sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(a_1, \dotsc, a_M)}
=\sum _{i_1=1}^N \dotsb \sum _{i_M=1}^N x_{i_1}^{a_1} \dotsb x_{i_M}^{a_M}
$$
Start with
$$
n (n-1) S^2
= (n-1) \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2)}
- \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(1,1)}
$$
I find that
\begin{align}
&n^2 (n-1)^2 S^4 \\
=&(n-1)^2 \left(
\sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(4)}
+2 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,2)}
\right)
-2 (n-1) \left(
2 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,1,1)}
+2 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(3,1)}
\right) \\
& \quad + \left(
24 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(1,1,1,1)}
+8 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,2)}
+8 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,1,1)}
\right)
\end{align}
giving
\begin{align}
&n^2 (n-1)^2 \mathbb{E} \left( S^4 \right) \\
=&(n-1)^2 \left[ n \mu_4 + 2 n (n-1) \mu_2^2 \right]
-2 (n-1) \left[ 2 n (n-1) (n-2) \mu_2 \mu_1^2 + 2 n (n-1) \mu_3 \mu_1 \right] \\
&\quad +\left[ 24 n (n-1) (n-2) (n-3) \mu_1^4 + 8 n (n-1) \mu_2^2 + 8 n (n-1) (n-2) \mu_2 \mu_1^2 \right]
\end{align}
This turns out to be wrong.
I am pretty sure I screw up some permutation factors before every $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it.
\begin{align}
&n^2 (n-1)^2 S^4 \\
=&(n-1)^2 \left(
\sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(4)}
+\sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,2)}
\right)
-2 (n-1) \left(
\sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,1,1)}
+2 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(3,1)}
\right) \\
& \quad + \left(
\sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(1,1,1,1)}
+2 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,2)}
+4 \sum _{\mathbf{x}} {\mathbf{x}}^{(2,1,1)}
\right)
\end{align}